# Memory upgrade scan tool not correct?

Tags: windows, memory, ddr2

I have an older computer I've been fixing up to use as a small server and i'm in the process of upgrading the RAM. (It only has 1GB.)

It's a Dell Dimension 9100.
Uses PC2-5300 DDR2.

It had windows xp (32 bit)

But I've installed Server 8 beta (64 bit hoping to be able to max the memory out at 8gb, 2GB per slot)

Thing is, all the upgrade detection tools I've run say that it maxes at 4GB.

Why would this be? The memory existes, and the OS should support it

Comment: Motherboard does not support it?

Comment: I guess it doesn't. Looked up the board and it says 4 GB max. That kinda shocks me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motherboard may not support it. Often something that is worth checking on older boards.